# Laravel 7 - Roles and Permissions

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-blade, user-roles

I am having trouble restricting menu options for user roles in Laravel 7. The menu for 'admin' and 'profesor' are similar but I decided to make two different views for each one and make an @include in the main view.

- User model

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'assigned_roles');
}
        
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->hasRoles(['admin']);
}
        
public function hasRoles(array $roles)
{
    foreach ($roles as $role) {
        foreach ($this->roles as $userRole) {
            if ($userRole->name === $role) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
        
public function userRole()
{
    return $this->role->nombre_rol; 
}
```

- My view

```xml
<hr class="hr-unam">
@if (auth()->user()->hasRoles(['admin']))
  <div class="sideover">
    <!-- *********************** SERVESCOL ***********************  -->
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
          <h5 class=" text-center panel-title">
            <a class="txt-unam txt-side font-weight-bold text-uppercase" style="text-decoration:none" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              SERVESCOL
            </a>
          </h5>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel-group" id="sub-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="subHeadingOne">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-accordion" href="#collapseSubOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSubOne">
                    @include('main.sidebarServescol')
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr-unam">
  @else
    @if(auth()->user()->hasRoles(['profesor']))
    <!-- *********************** SERVESCOL ***********************  -->
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class=" text-center panel-title">
              <a class="txt-unam txt-side font-weight-bold text-uppercase" style="text-decoration:none" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                SERVESCOL
              </a>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <div class="panel-group" id="sub-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                  <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="subHeadingOne">
                    <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-accordion" href="#collapseSubOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSubOne">
                      @include('main.sidebarProfesor')
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr class="hr-unam">
    @endif
  @endif
```

But both options disappear and the view breaks down. I have also tried it within the views of each menu directly, but in both, the role of 'admin' as in the role of 'profesor', remove the option that covers the @if.

Comment: `if (user is admin) { } else { if (user is admin) { ... } }`  thats not right (if they get to the `else` they are not an admin so checking if they are an admin would always be false there) ... you only have an `if` path basically

Comment: Oh yeah! Sorry, my mistake. But still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `hasRoles` function could be a bit simpler

```php
public function hasRoles(array $roles)
{
    return $this->roles->contains(function ($role, $key) use ($roles) {
        return in_array($role->name, $roles);
    });
}

// PHP 7.4 and above
public function hasRoles(array $roles)
{
    return $this->roles->contains(fn($role, $key) => in_array($role->name, $roles));
}
```

You could use the `@includeWhen` directive.

```xml
<hr class="hr-unam">
<div class="sideover">
  <!-- *********************** SERVESCOL ***********************  -->
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h5 class=" text-center panel-title">
          <a class="txt-unam txt-side font-weight-bold text-uppercase" style="text-decoration:none" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            SERVESCOL
          </a>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="panel-group" id="sub-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="subHeadingOne">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-accordion" href="#collapseSubOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseSubOne">
                  @includeWhen(auth()->user()->hasRoles(['admin']), 'main.sidebarServescol')
                  @includeWhen(auth()->user()->hasRoles(['profesor']), 'main.sidebarProfesor')
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It kinda works, the view doesn't look bad anymore but it doesn't display the options on the menu.

Comment: Your sidebars subviews might be at fault there

Comment: But it was working before. Whenever I add the role it fails. If I have nothing but the @include it works. Could it be something else besides the views?

Comment: It works already, I had something wrong with one of my methods. Thank you very much for your help! (: